# Why am I getting "runtime error (NZEC)" for this python code?(SPOJ Anti blot system)

Tags: python

I am getting runtime error (NZEC) for this python code even though it returns 0 when I run it on pycharm.

This is my first ever SPOJ problem and I'm new to python and coding in general. So please explain in layman's terms if possible

[link to problem:](https://www.spoj.com/problems/ABSYS/)

```py
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    s=input().split()
    c=0

    while c<len(s):
        if s[c].find('machula')>=0:
            err=c
        c+=2
    if err==0:
        new=str(int(s[4])-int(s[2]))
    elif err==2:
        new=str(int(s[4])-int(s[0]))
    elif err==4:
        new=str(int(s[0])+int(s[2]))

    s[err]=new
    print(s[0]+" "+s[1]+" "+s[2]+" "+s[3]+" "+s[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code, and means your program either did return with a non-zero exit code, or with an exception.

Did you actually test your application with the example input that was provided in the exercise? That's where the examples are intended for. If your program does not yield the correct result for the example input, then there's no point in submitting the solution. It will definitely fail then.

If your Python file is called 'absys.py' you should copy and paste the input (*without any modifications*) into a file 'input.txt' (for example) and then run:

```
python absys.py < input.txt
```

If I run your code with the example input I get a Python exception:

```
NameError: name 'err' is not defined
```

which explains the NZEC.

Also note the first comment on the page you linked:

> if anyone is getting runtime error try taking two getline() ..... one for line and one for the string.

...and carefully read the **Input specification** of the problem:

> "Each test case is preceded by a blank line."

Your code does not skip the blank lines, and that's what causes the above error. With a simple fix your application returns the correct output for the given example input.